# Infinite drill down in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've run into this over the years and just chalked it up to VS weirdness, but I'm curious if anyone has an explanation.

In my example below I'm using the mouse-over "drill down" on an exception to look at some values.  I noticed that if I go into the `Data` section (it's nearly faded out in the screen shot below, sorry) I can navigate down a seemingly endless chain of `Values->NodeKeyValueCollection->Non-Public Members->List` and then it goes back to `Values`.  I've gone over 30 levels deep in this drill down, with no end in sight.

Is there really something in the Exception object that goes on like this or is this a strange feature of mouse-over drill down?

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That just means that the list object has an internal member that references itself.  When you are debugging through it, that gives you the ability for infinite recursion.